# Is setInterval executed right upon declaration?

Tags: javascript

I was learning React and I saw this example, which is just a simple timer:

```
export default function Timer() {


const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  setTime((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, 1000);

  useEffect(()=>{
    return () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Time: {time}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

The timer automatically starts when I run this code, I wonder why is it that I never called **intervalId** after declaring it and it still runs automatically. So I am curious if **setInterval** is executed right upon declaration?

Comment: Yes, you can read it in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: `intervalId` is just an Number that can be used when cancelling the interval.

Comment: Why is React relevant at all here? If you're asking for `setInterval` then the only code useful for understanding it is the call to `setInterval` and the call to `clearInterval`. The rest is fluff at best, or might be misleading as it implies there is some "special rules" involved.

Comment: Of cause [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) is a function; as soon as one calls/invokes it, it will be executed. Of cause the function passed to `setInterval` executes delayed and repeatedly delayed according to the also passed `delay` parameter's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is setInterval executed right upon declaration?

Yes. You pass it a function, it calls that function every interval.

> I never called intervalId

The ID is an identifier used to **stop** the function from being called again. That is why you pass it to `clearInterval`.